# jQuery - Trigger event only once when press child inside father

Tags: jquery, dom

I have this code

```
<div class="div_father" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
  <h3>This is the div father</h3>
  <div class="div_child" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
   <p>This the div child.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is a div child inside a div father.
The original code, something happens when the user press over the child div.
Now I was asked to trigger the event when the user press any where inside the div father.

O could disable the function child, once it is inside the father, but I dont want t change the original code.

With this JS code, the event is trigged twice when the user cliks over child.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_father,.div_child').click(function () {
        alert("ok");
    });
});
```

Is there a way to avoid to be trigged twice?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qu30dka/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on your event. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8qu30dka/3/)

```
$('.div_father,.div_child').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the event from bubbling up from the child to the parent. You can do this simply by returning false from your handler, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_father,.div_child').click(function () {
        alert("ok");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using $('.div_father') should work.  But haven't tested it on all browsers yet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.div_father').click(function () {
        alert("ok");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_father" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
  <h3>This is the div father</h3>
  <div class="div_child" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
   <p>This the div child.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- stopPropagation
- test the target element against the father div

The example ([updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qu30dka/6/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.div_father,.div_child').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).is('.div_father')) {
         console.log("ok");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="div_father" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
  <h3>This is the div father</h3>
  <div class="div_child" style="color:#0000FF; border-style: ridge;">
   <p>This the div child.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```